# Azerothcore error azerothcore-wotlk-ac-worldserver-1 | MMAP:loadMap: 5303231.mmtile was built with generator v15, expected v16

Tags: docker, generator, mmap, azerothcore

I recently updated my Azerothcore docker version, but I am encountering an error: "azerothcore-wotlk-ac-worldserver-1 | MMAP:loadMap: 5303231.mmtile was built with generator v15, expected v16". I have tried deleting AC and installing from scratch following the guide on the Azerothcore website, but when I run "./acore.sh docker client-data", it is still downloading client data files for v15 instead of the latest version v16. I have followed the Docker Setup and Azerothcore Bash Dashboard setup, but I am still having issues. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds to me like a PR is required to fix the setup process of docker. If a manual swap of the client data isn't sufficient, only an adjustment of the docker script can solve this.

You should create an issue about it in the respective repo you've cloned, azerothcore-wotlk or acore-docker.

Edit: Please update and try again due to https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/pull/14527